# Bootstrap responsive background image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

How do I make, using bootstrap, a div holder having as background an image to fit to visitors display? The image has a fixed height and width. If the screen is smaller should be resized to do not have x,y overflow.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use `background-size` like this:

```
div.someclass {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

There's a good article from [@Chris Coyier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363927/chris-coyier) showing a few techniques: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 4):

First, for the background image:

```
div.someclass{ 
 background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

This will make your background image responsive, i.e. it will fit according to the size of the display the page is viewed on.

Second, to keep the main form content a proper margin from above on any device is to give the div you just created for the main content a relative margin on top:

```
div.someclass{
 margin-top:5%;
}
```

change the above 5% according to your requirement.

Comment: what is the difference between background-size and -webkit-background-size?

Comment: @ElSheikh It is added to support different browsers - webkit is for safari and other browsers based on the same engine, moz for Mozilla firefox, and o for opera.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very experienced in Bootstrap, but I think there is no such feature. I recommend you the create your own "Bootstrap Theme", a pure CSS or LESS file to customize your background.

You could simply use:

```
body
{
    background: url(https://www.google.hu/images/srpr/logo4w.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This code stretches your background image in both dimensions, but it cuts some parts of the image, unless the screen ration is the same as the image ratio.

```
body
{
    background: url(https://www.google.hu/images/srpr/logo4w.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
body{
        background-image: url('../url') ;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        height:100%;

    }
```